# Pause css animation when it's finished

Tags: css, css-animations

So I'm trying to animate some text dropping down once its finished animating.

The problem is it just disappears after it's finished, even though I set the opacity to 1@ 100%.

```
/* text animation */

@-webkit-keyframes textAnimation { 
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%);
    }
    10% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    20% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        -webkit-transform: translateY(0%);
    }

}




.text-animation {
    z-index: 1000;


    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-animation: textAnimation 2s linear  2s;
    -moz-animation: textAnimation 2s linear  2s;
    -o-animation: textAnimation 2s linear  2s;
    -ms-animation: textAnimation 2s linear  2s;
    animation: textAnimation 2s linear  2s;
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: 1;
      -webkit-animation-delay: 1s;
    -moz-animation-delay: 1s;
    -o-animation-delay: 1s;
    -ms-animation-delay: 1s;
    animation-delay: 1s;
}

/* text animation */
```

I just don't understand what the problem is here...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me.

If you set the end state in the class and not add a delay.

```
@-webkit-keyframes textAnimation {
    0% { opacity: 0; -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%); }
    33% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(-200%); }
    100% { opacity: 1; -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); }
}

.text-animation {
color:#fff;
font-size:32px;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
opacity: 1;
-webkit-animation: textAnimation 3s linear;
-moz-animation: textAnimation 3s linear;
-o-animation: textAnimation 3s linear;
-ms-animation: textAnimation 3s linear;
animation: textAnimation 3s linear;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In you .text-animation declaration add this :

```
-webkit-animation-fill-mode: forwards;
```

Thanks to it, your animation will stay to the last keyframe state. (here, opacity 0).

You can see the result here : http://codepen.io/joe/pen/CkbcL

Source : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-fill-mode